# How do I rebind `hjkl` to `jkl;`

Tags: vim, neovim, touch-typing

I've been trying to rebind to proper touch typing keys, and
it's actually more complicated I expected. This is my init.vim:

```
" Normal mode
nmap ; <Right>
nmap l <Up>
nmap k <Down>
nmap j <Left>
nnoremap h ;

" Visual mode
vmap ; <Right>
vmap l <Up>
vmap k <Down>
vmap j <Left>
vnoremap h ;

" Rebind the window-switching movements
nnoremap <C-w>; <C-w>l
nnoremap <C-w>l <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-w>k <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-w>j <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w>h <C-w>;
```

Looks fine, right? Except it's not. By default in vim, when you press `Ctrl + W + k`, your window will switch, regardless if you pressed `k` with `Ctrl + W` already being pressed down or in succession to `Ctrl + W`. However, with my key rebinds, the movement key must be pressed after releasing `Ctrl + W`. This ruins my workflow, as sometimes, I try to quickly switch window, and I fail because I didn't release `Ctrl + W` quick enough.

How can I achieve a proper keybind without making window-switching less convenient? Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably have a better chance at an answer at vim.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `:help CTRL-W_j` and its friends, you will see that they all have a bunch of alternatives. The important one is `<C-w><C-j>`, which is what lets you keep your left pinky on `Ctrl` while you press `j` with the right index *or* keep your left pinky and index on `Ctrl` and `w` while you press `j` with the right index.

Therefore:

```
[...]
nnoremap <C-w>j <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-w><C-j> <C-w>h
[...]
```